# loop multiple row data to a single row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, text

I am extracting data points from a multi line text file and and trying to add the group data to a single row in the dataframe, but I am getting each data point on its own row I would like to flatten this to 2 rows group1 and group2. I am new to python. Also if there is a more efficient way to do this that would be great too. I have tried `groupby()` but this did not seem to work? Thanks in advance.

```python
import pandas as pd

data = """
Jan 2024
Group1 02/02/2024
dog 10 20
cat 21 32
Group2 05/02/2024
dog 23 45
cat 45 65
owl 24 12
monthly
Admin 02 22
clean 05 32
"""

extract = []
dog, cat, owl = [], [], []
for line in data.splitlines():
    a = c = e = ''
    # print(line)
    if 'Group' in line:
        group = line.rsplit()[0]
    
    if 'dog' in line or 'cat' in line or 'owl' in line:
        if line.startswith("dog"):
            dog, a, b = line.split()
        elif line.startswith("cat"):
            cat, c, d = line.split()
        elif line.startswith("owl"):
            owl, e, f = line.split()
        
        extract.append({
            'group': group,
            'dog': a,
            'cat': c,
            'owl': e
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(extract)
df = df[['group', 'dog', 'cat', 'owl']]
print(df)
```

### Currently I am getting the following:

```
    group dog cat owl
0  Group1  10
1  Group1      21
2  Group2  23
3  Group2      45
4  Group2          24
```

### What I would like is:

```
   group dog cat owl
0  Group1  10 21
1  Group2  23 45  24
```

Comment: The  script gives error: `raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")` And indentation is wrong.

Comment: add `df = df.fillna('').groupby('group').agg(''.join)` before the print statement

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes it does. Thanks for the help. I see it can also export with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collapse rows before constructing a dataframe. This can be achieved by maintaining one `dict` `column_name->value` per group, refreshing it when a new group starts and adding it as a row right before that. Don't forget to add a row in the very end.

```
extract = []
row = None

for line in data.splitlines():
    if 'Group' in line:
        if row is not None: # we have something to add
            extract.append(row)
        group = line.rsplit()[0]
        row = {'group': group} # new group starts - refreshing our dict
    
    if 'dog' in line or 'cat' in line or 'owl' in line:
        animal, val1, val2 = line.split()
        row[animal] = val1
        
if row is not None: # a final group
    extract.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(extract)
df = df[['group', 'dog', 'cat', 'owl']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    group dog cat  owl
0  Group1  10  21  NaN
1  Group2  23  45   24
```

Comment: Thanks I like your solution as it sets it up before the df. I was wondering how to do this as a dict from the start